# Inserting nodes locations for network graph D3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am trying to solve a homework.

I am trying plot a network graph by drawing the nodes from this dataset(sample).

> {   "nodes": [
>       {
>         "id": "site09",
>         "x": 317.5,
>         "y": 282.5
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "site01",
>         "x": 112,
>         "y": 47
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "site03",
>         "x": 69.5,
>         "y": 287
>       },
>       {
>         "id": "site04",
>         "x": 424.5,
>         "y": 99.5
>       } ]
>
> "links": [
>       {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site08", "amount": 10},
>       {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site02", "amount": 120},
>       {"node01": "site05", "node02": "site03", "amount": 50},

I want to plot the location of the circles using x and y from the dataset.

I tried the following but the circles/nodes are not showing.

```
//importing the json data
    d3.json("project.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        svgCanvas.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data).enter() // create place hodlers if the data are new .append("circle") // create one circle for each
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", function(data){
            return data.x;})
        .attr("cy", function(data){
            return data.y;})
        .attr("r", function(thisElement, index){
              // use the value from data to create the radius
        return thisElement["amount"]})

        vis.selectAll("circle.nodes")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "black") 

    })
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: I am using this line from D3 website

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi @sue.  A few things.  I'm not sure if the data ever get in there properly.  You didn't quote that part. The two big blocks of code look repetitive to me. The first never appears to set radius.  The second block of code looks like it should work if the data gets in there.  I'd drop in a call to `debugger` and run w/ console open, so that you can inspect and see if your assumptions match what's actually happening.  Also - `.append("svg:circle")` can be just `.append("circle")`.   I'm not sure if having the `svg:` there harms, but I don't think it helps.

Comment: hi Laizer, thanks for your reply. I got feedback from my tutor that I need to use ES6 maps to connect nodes and links.